# pygsp code working on python shell but not when I execute it from terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I type on my terminal:

```
python3
```

and then:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from pygsp import graphs, filters, plotting

>>> plotting.BACKEND = 'matplotlib'
>>> plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)

>>> rs = np.random.RandomState(42)
>>> W = rs.uniform(size=(30, 30))
>>> W[W < 0.93] = 0
>>> W = W + W.T
>>> np.fill_diagonal(W, 0)
>>> G = graphs.Graph(W)

>>> G.set_coordinates('ring2D')
>>> G.plot()
```

I can see the graph plot.
Here is an image:
[Code working on python shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHUiC.png)

But If I put the exact same content on a file (I am using test.py)
and I run:

```
python3 sample.py
```

Then I see no image at all.
Here is an image:
[Code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4dJp.png)

What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it? Thank you.

I tried putting a sleep after the plot function thinking that maybe image was being opened and immediately closed but that didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found that I was missing a plt.show(), with that It works. I would still like to know why that is not needed when using the python shell. Another thing I noticed is that If I run the code as `python -i test.py` it also works